# How to make lseek64 _actually_ return 64-bit offset?

Tags: linux, large-files, libc, seek, ftell

```
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64 
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE    

...

off64_t st_size; 

...

st_size = (off64_t)lseek64(fd, (off64_t)0, SEEK_END);
fprintf(stderr, "QQQ st_size=%llx %lld\n", st_size, st_size);
```

Then strace:

```
$ strace -e _llseek ./the_program
_llseek(3, 0, [20974464000], SEEK_END)  = 0
QQQ st_size=ffffffffe22cec00 -500372480
```

- 20974464000 == 0x4E22CEC00 - good
- -500372480 == 0xffffffffe22cec00 - bad

It change to `(off64_t)lseek64(fd, 0, SEEK_END);` it calls _llseek incorrectly:

```
_llseek(3, 8589934592, [8589934592], SEEK_SET) = 0
st_size=0 0
```

What more should I do to ensure it gets the size correctly, without chopping off major dword?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure you're defining `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` and `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` **before** including sys/types.h and unistd.h. Preferably, in you compiler's command line.

Comment: Yes, they are before. There are only comments before.

Comment: ... Hovever sys/types.h and unistd.h are just not included at all. The essential mistake is forgetting about "-Wall".